# How to group different versions of names as one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have **scraped** some data from a website. It has different spellings for same name. I want the different spellings to be combined as one. The names are as such -

'WARANGAL(RURA L)', 'WARANGAL(RURAL)', 'WARANGAL(RUR AL)' - these I want as 'WARANGAL (RURAL)'

'WARANGAL(URBAN)', 'WARANGAL (URBAN)' - these I want as 'WARANGAL (URBAN)'

'JANGOAN', 'JANGAON' - these I want as 'JANGAON'

'NAGARKURNOOL', 'NAGARKURNOO L' - these I want as 'NAGARKURNOOL'

'KUMRAMBHEE M ASIFABAD', 'KUMRAMBHEEMASIFABAD', 'KUMRAMBHEEM ASIFABAD' - these I want as 'KUMRAMBHEEM ASIFABAD'

I tried using `str.stip()` but it didn't work out

I tried below solution

I first created a list of similar names and then using masking, I changed the name to the one I wanted to using for loop.

```
y1 = ['WARANGAL(RURA L)', 'WARANGAL(RURAL)', 'WARANGAL(RUR AL)']
for i in range(0, len(y1)):
    df1[df1['District']==y1[i]] = 'WARANGAL(RURAL)'
```

Where, df1 is the dataframe consisting of the data I collected

But now, the issue is it modified the entire row where that particular name is present. How should I prevent it from happening?

Comment: To remove spaces you ca user str.strip().replace(' ', '').
For things like 'JANGOAN', 'JANGAON' it can be a lot more complicated, and you may need to do something like machine learning, clustering

Comment: For words like  'JANGOAN' and 'JANGAON', look up "phonetic distance" algorithms. Example: Levenshtein distance.

Comment: I assume you are using pandas: [DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)